# console app to powershell for SharePoint om

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2010

Is it possible to convert this blog code from console app to powershell? if yes, how?

http://digsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/11/retrieving-credentials-from-secure.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just create a class library DLL with exactly the same code and just load this DLL in your PowerShell using

```
 #Load assemblies (needed for SharePoint Server)
 [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("YourDllNameSpace")
```

This will load from the GAC but you can also specify LoadFile and path to DLL.

See [this](http://www.dougfinke.com/blog/index.php/2010/08/29/how-to-load-net-assemblies-in-a-powershell-session/) post for more information.

Hope it helps,

Andrew